# Facebook FQL query event doesn't return correct result

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-fql

I am building a query to retrieve all events created by Page ID. The query is simple and look like the following:

```
SELECT eid, name, pic_big, start_time,creator, end_time, location, description FROM event WHERE creator="153504361606" order by start_time desc
```

It returns only two events with very old date: 2009-10. But at the fan page, it has a lot more events.

I tried to replace the page id with other fan pages, all looked fine. It is just '153504361606' has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, I filed it for you here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/653769257984873

you can subscribe to follow it.